# Is it possible to have overfitting due to high bias?

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting, bias-variance-tradeoff

Overfitting is usually associated with high variance, whereas underfitting is associated with high bias. But one of my professors at uni mentioned that overfitting might be caused by high variance and/or bias. I'm trying to understand how it is possible that it might be caused by bias.

Someone pointed me out an example, and I don't know if its correct. Let's say that we train a model to classify between pictures of old and young people in a data set where all old people aren't smiling and all young people are smiling. And then the model, instead of predicting features that would actually discriminate between young and old, would learn to classify the two solely by taking into account the presence of a smile. So, during the test phase, if we were to show the model a picture of someone young not smiling, it would predict an old person.
Would this case be an overfitting due to high bias? The model not being able to maintain a more flexible classification zone and take into account the variance of other features in the data?

Comment: I'm not sure I would call this "overfitting", but in any case it isn't *due to* high bias; the causality flows in the opposite direction, from the estimation procedure's confounding of smiles with youth to bias.

Comment: I think we could call it overfitting, in the sense that the training is increasing training accuracy at the expense of generalization, due to specific quirks of the training dataset.

Comment: This sounds more like distribution shift rather than overfitting.